# How to break a callback chain in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, callback

I am uploading multiple files from a browser and need to do so sequentially.

So I chain the next upload commencement from the previous upload completion callback.

It's simple and works just fine.

During the upload I display the progress to the user along with a cancel button.

If the user hits cancel I want to stop the entire callback chain.

How would I do that?  Is there some mechanism in JavaScript to halt my callback chain?

OK here is an example of a callback chain in JavaScript.  The question is, how to break it from a "cancel" button?

https://jsfiddle.net/jq7m9beq/

```
var filenamesToProcessQueue = ['v.jpg','w.jpg','x.jpg','y.jpg','z.jpg']

function finishedProcessing (filename) {
console.log('finished processing: ' + filename)
// processing finished for this file, start again by chaining to the next one
doProcessFiles()
}

function waitForEachFile (filename, callback) {
// wait a couple of seconds and log the filename
setTimeout(function(){ console.log('Waited 2 seconds for: ' + filename);callback(filename);}, 2000)

}

function doProcessFiles() {
// get next file to process and remove it from the queue at same time
filename = filenamesToProcessQueue.pop()
// if the file is undefined then the queue was empty
if (typeof filename !== 'undefined') {
console.log('Process ' + filename)
waitForEachFile(filename, finishedProcessing)
}
}

doProcessFiles()
```

Comment: You need to share your code

Comment: Why?  I don't have a problem with my code.  I'm asking how to break chains of callbacks.  What would my code tell you?

Comment: Code will tell us how you are constructing callback chains and how you want to interrupt it.

Comment: It would give us informations on what the situation is and, depending on it, we could provide you the best answer. Otherwise it's like flying blind!
However if the chain is built with nested callbacks, you could just break it using a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click of a cancel button, set a flag

```
var cancelFlag = false;
document.getElementById("cancelBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
   cancelFlag = true;
   //other code
});
```

change your doProcess to

```
function doProcessFiles() 
{
    if (cancelFlag)
    {
      return false; //this will break the chain
    }
    // get next file to process and remove it from the queue at same time
    filename = filenamesToProcessQueue.pop()
    // if the file is undefined then the queue was empty
    if (typeof filename !== 'undefined') 
    {
       console.log('Process ' + filename)
       waitForEachFile(filename, finishedProcessing)
    }
}
```

You can also stop your waiting

```
function waitForEachFile (filename, callback) 
{
    if (cancelFlag)
    {
        return false; //this will stop waiting as well
    }
   // wait a couple of seconds and log the filename
   setTimeout(function(){ console.log('Waited 2 seconds for: ' +   filename);callback(filename);}, 2000)
}
```

you can set the flag in the cancel button itself

```
document.getElementById("cancelBtn").setAttribute("data-flag", "true");
```

and check this value

```
var cancelFlag = Boolean(document.getElementById("cancelBtn").getAttribute("data-flag"));
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.  Thanks Gurvinder.